# html rendering in ruby

Tags: html, ruby, markdown

I am attempting to include a markdown file in my HTML.

currently i have

```
Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML).render(
  File.read(File.join(Dir.pwd, 'README.md'))
)
```

Which brings in the contents just fine, aside from properly rendering the html.

my source shows:

`&lt;h1&gt;Header&lt;&#47;h1&gt;`

whcih shows the html markup in the browser:

`<h1>Header</h1>`

I have been playing with this awhile.  Looking for answers always ends me up with rails html_safe helper, but i am not using rails.  I have tried CGI.unescapeHTML and HTMLEntities.  What am i missing here?

Comment: What system are you using to get that content into the browser? It's likely that it's doing some kind of XSS protection by escaping HTML entities.

Comment: this is running from a middleman project using slim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using the slim template engine?

in the template you should be able to just do

```
p== my_var
```

or

```
p
  | some text with unescaped html: #{{my_var}}
```

see the [docs](https://github.com/stonean/slim#text-interpolation).